# Is $(0,0)$ a saddle point for the given function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I need to find the critical points for the function

$f(x) = 3(x^2 + y^2) - 2(x^3 - y^3) + 6xy$ and also test whether they are maxima/minima/saddle point.

Now the only critical point is (0,0)

however at (0,0) $rt - s^2  =0$ then second derivative test fails,

If I take the line $y = -x$ then

$f(x, -x) = -4x^3$ then clearly for along the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ $f$ has both positive and negative values .

Hence , $(0,0)$ is a  saddle point .

Is my solution and answer correct ? Can someone please verify ?

Thank you.

Comment: You have right,$P(0,0)$ is a saddle point

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Thank you.

Comment: Observe that this function can be written as 
$$f(x,y)=3(x^2+y^2)+6xy-2(x^3-y^3)=3(x+y)^2-2(x^3-y^3).$$ That makes it more obvious that the line $x+y=0$ is of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments, I am just answering for the sake of completeness so that it does not remain unsolved.

The process is correct and $(0,0)$  is the saddle point for the given function.